# Randomly get 504 Gateway Time-out after 40seconds

Tags: php, laravel, timeout, guzzle, gateway

My server is running Apache, FPM/FastCGI, and PHP 5.5.30.

I have Laravel 5.0 framework and Guzzle to manage different kind of HTTP requests.

Before Guzzle I used Rolling-Curl to make requests in paraller. Reason why I changed Rolling-Curl to Guzzle is that I got randomly 504 Gateway errors, but after couple of tests I noticed that I got it even with Guzzle.

Gateway error happens always after 40seconds and it happens randomly. If I hit couple of times F5 (refresh) it goes away, but can occur later again.

Following is my code snippet

```
$feeds = Feeds::where('active', '=', '1')->lists('url');  

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requests = array();

foreach($feeds AS $feed)
{
  $requests[] = $client->createRequest('GET', $feed);
}

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests, [
  'pool_size' => '5',
  'timeout' => '120',
  'connect_timeout' => '120',
  'complete' => function (CompleteEvent $event) {
    echo 'Completed request to ' . $event->getRequest()->getUrl() . " - ". $event->getResponse()->getStatusCode() . "\n";
    //echo 'Response: ' . $event->getResponse()->getBody() . "\n\n";
  },       
  'error' => function (ErrorEvent $event) {
      echo 'Request failed: ' . $event->getRequest()->getUrl() . "\n";
      echo $event->getException();
  }
]);


$pool->wait();

echo "...done in " . (microtime(true) - $start);
?>
```

`$feeds` is getting 100 RSS URLs from database and my pool is getting content of max 5 feeds at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the exact error you are getting and possibly identify the line of your code indicated for where the exception is being thrown? I think there are 2 things you can do either separately or in combination to resolve the error:

add a `'rejected'` function to your Pool initiation options to handle failed requests, see the [Guzzle documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)

wrap the line of your code throwing the error in a `try {} catch {} block` if the `'rejected' function`option alone is not fixing it

See your code as amended below to include my suggestions:

```
$feeds = Feeds::where('active', '=', '1')->lists('url');  

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$requests = array();

foreach($feeds AS $feed)
{
    $requests[] = $client->createRequest('GET', $feed);
}

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests, [
  'pool_size' => '5',
  'timeout' => '120',
  'connect_timeout' => '120',
  'complete' => function (CompleteEvent $event) {
    echo 'Completed request to ' . $event->getRequest()->getUrl() . " - ". $event->getResponse()->getStatusCode() . "\n";
    //echo 'Response: ' . $event->getResponse()->getBody() . "\n\n";
  },       
  'error' => function (ErrorEvent $event) {
      echo 'Request failed: ' . $event->getRequest()->getUrl() . "\n";
      echo $event->getException();
   },
   //add the 'rejected' function
   'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
       //handle failed requests here
   },
]);

//throw in the try{} catch {} block if the 'rejected' function is not fixing the 504 error
try {
    //your code goes here...I suspect it's the $pool->wait()
    $promise = $pool->promise(); //I included this line from the Guzzle documentation
    $promise->wait();
} catch (ServerException $e) {
    //Catch exception for 504 error here; you probabbly want to retry recursively a number of times before giving up...
}

echo "...done in " . (microtime(true) - $start);
```